# Mongomapper: does "_id" field conflict with "id"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongomapper

I have a collection which contains both _id and id field. When I search by id field in mongo client everything is fine. When I search through mongomapper model like: Product.find_by_id(6) or Product.where(:id => 6) it return empty Plucky object and I can see that it looks for an _id field instead of id.

As I understand mongomapper just always using _id, no matter if you specifically want to find something by id.

Is there any work around for it or I'm doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I believe MongoMapper treats `id` and `_id` both equally. `id` is just a friendlier representation of `_id`.

In your particular case, is there any reason that you need to have the `id` field as well? I'd recommend changing that, particularly if there is another more descriptive name which would fit. If you are actually using the `id` field as a unique identifier (which it sounds like you might be), the best approach would probably be to store it in the `_id` field instead. As you will already be aware, this is required on all MongoDB documents and can either be specified by you (your application), or added on later by your driver outside of the scope of your application code.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, which version are you referring to? We're on 0.9.2, and for some reason it seems to treat "id" different from "_id". Is there a setting we need to enable? For instance, "Game.id" returns nil whereas "Game._id" (on the next line) returns a mongo ID as expected.

Comment: I can't remember now - it would have either been the current version or a recent version at time of writing this answer. Likely 0.8.x. I've not tested it lately though, so it is entirely possible the behaviour has changed. I still maintain my belief however that having both 'id' and '_id' is asking for a bit of pain, and would suggest an alternative design if possible/appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by this issue (https://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper/issues/195) if you ever had an instance with a key of "id." Mongo remembers *every* key from every instance, unless you clear the key explicitly.